# Is there a way to zoom with the front camera on an iPhone (iOS 13.5.1)?

Tags: iphone, camera

I'm running iOS 13.5.1 on an iPhone XR. I can zoom with the back camera (in by "spreading", out by "pinching"), but is there a way to zoom with the front camera?

Answer (score 1):

Go to this website and purchase the App from the App Store. Once installed you also zoom with the front camera. https://camera.plus

Comment: Thank you for responding to the request for details such as a link. Having that usually avoids down votes but isn’t strictly required. I will edit the side conversation as answers are best when not chatty and they address the question and not side bar comments.

Comment: Many thanks for this answer, @JanD. But can you post a link confirming that this program does indeed allow front zoom on the XR. I couldn't find that stated at the site you linked to, unless it was implied in jargon I didn't understand. Thanks again for your help. I should add that I'd welcome other answers too. Digital zoom seems quite a simple thing, so there may be some free programs out there that provide this function.

Answer (score -1):

With the app Camera+ you can zoom the front camera.

Comment: It’s helpful if you provide a link to the app and maybe even a description of how it can solve the problem

Comment: As a courtesy to explain my comment earlier, your original post as flagged as “Low Quality” and my comment is offered as **constructive criticism** in case you could  make your answer better.  I highly suggest you review our [Code of Conduct](https://apple.stackexchange.com/conduct) in regards to your last comment and [help] for site expectations on commenting, flagging and voting.

Comment: I edited Allan’s post above and removed an out of bounds rude comment. Hit me up on [meta] if anyone isn’t clear how to vote or post.